# Does anyone experience the black frame around emails in Evolution?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, evolution

Emails in Evolution 3.10.4 are surounded by a black frame. I use Lubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit.

The screenshot is here: 
[image]

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of said frame to imgur and provide the link here.

Comment: You got down votes because you hadn't really asked a question. Now you've edited to clarify, I've just undone that down vote - and up voted in fact.